# inserting multiple rows from csv to mysql and seeing progress using AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv

I have a CSV file with more than 10,000 rows or records. I already know how to insert them in MySQL.  What I want is to have an interactive notification of how many rows or columns have been inserted so far?

Example:

100 of 10000 rows inserted

I tried using AJAX and here is my code.

```
function insert_logs(filename) {
    //alert("Inserting Data!!!" + filename);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200) {
            _("logStatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
        }
    }
    ajax.open("GET","insert_logs_module.php?fileName="+filename,true);
    ajax.send();
}
```

and here is my insert_logs_module.php code :

```
if (file_exists ( $targetFile)) {

    $data = fopen( $targetFile , 'r' );

    $numRows = count(file($targetFile,FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));

    /*$sql = mysql_query( "select * from logs where vessel_token = '" . $vessel_token . "'") or die("Error Select Logs - " . mysql_error());

    if( mysql_num_rows( $sql ) > 0 ){
        mysql_query("delete from logs where $vessel_token = '" . $vessel_token . "'" ) or die("Error Vessel Delete - " . mysql_error());
    }
    */
    $processRowCount = 0;
    $csvContent = fgetcsv( $data, 1000, "," );
    $traj_id = 0;
    $previousDate = 0;
    while( $csvContent = fgetcsv( $data, 1000, "," ) )
    {
        $ts = strtotime($csvContent[2]);
        $date =  date('Y/m/d',$ts);
        $logged_day = date('l',$ts);
        if ($previousDate != $date)
        {
            $traj_id++; 
        }
        $lat = $csvContent[2];
        $lon = $csvContent[1];
        $logged_at = $csvContent[3];

        mysql_query("insert into logs (vessel_token,traj_id,lat,lon,logged_at,logged_day) values ('" . $csvContent[0] . "','" . $traj_id . "','" . $lat . "','" . $lon . "','" . $logged_at . "','" . $logged_day . "');") or die("Error Insert - " . mysql_error());
       $previousDate = $date;
       $processRowCount++;
       $percent = ($processRowCount/$numRows) * 100;
       echo "$percent-$processRowCount of $numRows Records Processed!";
    }
} else {
        echo "File Does Not Exists! $targetFile";   
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Use load in file function of mysql. And dont use mysql_ extensions

Comment: thanks for the response Indra, but can you tell me more? I am sorry I am just starting in developing websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Upload a csv file and use Load in file mysql fn.

form.php

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="upload.php">
 Send this file: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
 </form>
```

upload.php

```
    <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
    $target_path = "";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        $file_name = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];  
        echo "The file ".basename($file_name)." has been uploaded";  
        mysqli_query($con,"LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_name' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'");
    } else {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
    ?>
```

The method you are using currently will hog the resources

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the path for the filename because it searches for the file not in my uploads folder but the load data infile uses the path for mysql\data?

Answer (score 0):

Try using 2 AJAX call, one is for inserting the data and set a count variable. The other one is for checking the progress on the first ajax call on the backend retrieving the count variable. Don't forget to put the 2nd ajax call on an interval maybe a second or half.